# XQuery [value()] issue for Dynamic SQL variable in Select Stateemt

Tags: sql, xml, xquery, msg

I'm try to make the code below dynamic as there can be different names for the 'name' attribute in the page 'node'.

When I run the code below it returns the error 'XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *''

I feel my main issue is in the line
'C.value('(/level1/level2/template/page/@name)[sql:variable("@Counter")]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Page Name]'
where I am trying to make '@counter' variable dynamic.

Does anyone have any solutions please?

XML FOR ID 9371

```
<level1>
  <level2>
    <template width="594" height="500">
      <page Cid="1" name="Test Page Name" colour="-3355393">
        <image Cid="8" x="432" y="8" w="148" h="95" KeyImage="32861" Ratio="y" />
        <formattedText Cid="14" x="9" y="22" w="253" h="38">
          <p>
            <p>
              Text
            </p>
          </p>
        </formattedText>
      </page>
      <page Cid="6" name="Properties">
        <formattedText Cid="7" x="200" y="148" w="208" h="228">
          <p>
            <p>
              <t>Created by </t>
              <t b="b">Joe Bloggs</t>
            </p>
            <p />
            <p>
              <t>Date published 30/05/2017</t>
            </p>
        </formattedText>
      </page>
    </template>
  </level2>
</level1>
```

RESULTS FROM SQL Query

** Present Result

```
Page Name   | Demographics  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Page Name  | <page Cid="1" name="Test Page Name" colour="-3355393"><image Cid="8" x="432" y="8" w="148" h="95" KeyImage="32861" Ratio="y" /><formattedText Cid="14" x="9" y="22" w="253" h="38"><p><p>Text</p></p> </formattedText></page>
Test Page Name  | <page><formattedText Cid="7" x="200" y="148" w="208" h="228"><p><p> <t>Created by </t><t b="b">Joe Bloggs</t></p><p /><p><t>Date published 30/05/2017</t> </p></formattedText></page>
```

** Desired Result

```
Page Name   | Demographics  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Page Name  | <page Cid="1" name="Test Page Name" colour="-3355393"><image Cid="8" x="432" y="8" w="148" h="95" KeyImage="32861" Ratio="y" /><formattedText Cid="14" x="9" y="22" w="253" h="38"><p><p>Text</p></p> </formattedText></page>
Properties  | <page><formattedText Cid="7" x="200" y="148" w="208" h="228"><p><p> <t>Created by </t><t b="b">Joe Bloggs</t></p><p /><p><t>Date published 30/05/2017</t> </p></formattedText></page> 



DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(40),
 @opxml AS XML,
 @hDoc AS INT,
 @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
   


SELECT @opxml = 
a.[filedata]
FROM [database].[dbo].[xmlfile2] a
where  [Id] = 9371

DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @MaxNo INT 
SET @Counter=1
SET @MaxNo=(SELECT
COUNT(CAST('<page>' +  CAST(C.query('./child::node()') as nvarchar(max)) + '</page>' as xml))
FROM @opxml.nodes('/level1/level2/template/page') AS T(C))

WHILE ( @Counter <= @MaxNo)
BEGIN

SELECT
C.value('(/level1/level2/template/page/@name)[sql:variable("@Counter")]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS         
[Page Name],
CAST('<page>' +  CAST(C.query('./child::node()') as nvarchar(max)) + '</page>' as xml) AS     [Page_XML]
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.c)
FROM @opxml.nodes('/level1/level2/template/page') AS T(C)


SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Does using `(/level1/level2/template/page/@name)[position() = sql:variable("@Counter")]` instead of `(/level1/level2/template/page/@name)[sql:variable("@Counter")]` improve things?

Comment: Note that the XML sample is not well-formed, a closing `</p>` tag is missing. As for the whole task, do you want to extract the existing `page` elements? I don't quite understand why the first result row has the original `page` with its attributes while the second result row has a simple `page` without the attributes from the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
SELECT
  C.value('@name','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Page Name],
  C.query('<page>{node()}</page>') AS [Page_XML], 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.c)
FROM @opxml.nodes('/level1/level2/template/page') AS T(C)
```

might suffice to produce the wanted result without the need for a WHILE loop.

I think the original problem with the long path inside of `value()` (e.g. `C.value('(/level1/level2/template/page/@name)[sql:variable("@Counter")]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')`) is due to the static type checking of XQuery in SQL server and to avoid it you basically need to add another predicate that ensures the type checker knows a single value is returned e.g. `C.value('(/level1/level2/template/page/@name)[sql:variable("@Counter")][1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')`

For me, the code

```
DECLARE @opxml AS XML

SET @opxml = N'<level1>
  <level2>
    <template width="594" height="500">
      <page Cid="1" name="Test Page Name" colour="-3355393">
        <image Cid="8" x="432" y="8" w="148" h="95" KeyImage="32861" Ratio="y" />
        <formattedText Cid="14" x="9" y="22" w="253" h="38">
          <p>
            <p>
              Text
            </p>
          </p>
        </formattedText>
      </page>
      <page Cid="6" name="Properties">
        <formattedText Cid="7" x="200" y="148" w="208" h="228">
          <p>
            <p>
              <t>Created by </t>
              <t b="b">Joe Bloggs</t>
            </p>
            <p />
            <p>
              <t>Date published 30/05/2017</t>
            </p>
          </p>
        </formattedText>
      </page>
    </template>
  </level2>
</level1>'

SELECT
  C.value('@name','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Page Name],
  C.query('<page>{node()}</page>') AS [Page_XML], 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.c)
FROM @opxml.nodes('/level1/level2/template/page') AS T(C)
```

produces the table

```
Page Name   Page_XML    (Kein Spaltenname)
Test Page Name  <page><image Cid="8" x="432" y="8" w="148" h="95" KeyImage="32861" Ratio="y" /><formattedText Cid="14" x="9" y="22" w="253" h="38"><p><p>
              Text
            </p></p></formattedText></page> 1
Properties  <page><formattedText Cid="7" x="200" y="148" w="208" h="228"><p><p><t>Created by </t><t b="b">Joe Bloggs</t></p><p /><p><t>Date published 30/05/2017</t></p></p></formattedText></page> 2
```

so at least the `Page_Name` seems to be easily populated by using e.g. `C.value('@name','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Page Name]`

Comment: Thanks, but neither has helped :(

Comment: Have now given more to what I am trying to achieve in my original question.